# Error Handling multiple column list in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I have a list with two fields -name and type. I am trying to add rows of these two items and save them in state, so that the corresponding name and type are in one object,inside the state columns which is an array of objects. But after the add option  i.e in handleColumnChange function only the 'type' attribute is getting saved in the column array. I figured that I am using the assign operator wrong, but I cannot figure out how to take two of these inputs and update the state simultaneously. Any help regarding how to handle this will be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
   super()
   this.state = {
    columns: [{ name: '' ,type:''}],
   }
  }

  handleColumnChange = (idx) => (event) => {
   const newColumns = this.state.columns.map((column, sidx) => {
   if (idx !== sidx){
    return column;
   } else{
    let name,type;
    if (event.target.name === "name"){
      name=event.target.value;
    }
    if (event.target.name === "type")
      type=event.target.value;

    return { ...column, name: name, type:type };
   }
  });

  this.setState({ columns: newColumns });
 }

handleSubmit = (evt) => {
 const { columns } = this.state;
 alert(JSON.stringify(this.state));
}

handleAddColumn = () => {
 this.setState({ columns: this.state.columns.concat([{ 
   name:'',type:''}]) });
  }

 handleRemoveColumn = (idx) => () => {
   this.setState({ columns: this.state.columns.filter((s, sidx) => idx 
!== sidx) });
}

render () {
 return (
  <div className='App'>
    <p className='App-intro'>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <h4>Columns</h4>

    {this.state.columns.map((column, id) => (
      <div className="Columns">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          placeholder={`ColumnName #${id + 1} name`}
          value={column.name}
          onChange={this.handleColumnChange(id)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="type"
          placeholder={`ColumnType #${id + 1} name`}
          value={column.type}
          onChange={this.handleColumnChange(id)}
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleRemoveColumn(id)} className="small">-</button>
      </div>
    ))}
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleAddColumn} className="small">Add Column</button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("This is the state",this.state);
          }}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </p>
  </div>
)
}
}
export default App
```

Comment: In your else: `let { name, type } = column;` otherwise you keep overwriting the other value with `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the issue.